# ASP.Net core Web API vs ASP.Net WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I have Implemented a simple code using ASP.net WCF and ASP.Net core Web API which can be called using post method.

ASP.Net WCF:

```
public class service : Iservice
{
    public string banner() { return "OK"; }
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface Iservice
{
    [WebInvoke(Method="POST",UriTemplate = "/test",                
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    [OperationContract]
    string banner();       
}
```

ASP.Net core Web API:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class TodoController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public string item()
    {
        return "OK";
    }
}
```

`program.cs` is implemented as the following:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseUrls("http://localhost:80")
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();

    host.Run();
}
```

and `sturtup.cs` is implemented as:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

        if (env.IsEnvironment("Development"))
        {
            builder.AddApplicationInsightsSettings(developerMode: true);
        }

        builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);
        services.AddSingleton<ITodoRepository, TodoRepository>();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        app.UseApplicationInsightsRequestTelemetry();

        app.UseApplicationInsightsExceptionTelemetry();

        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

When I host these 2 projects on IIS and using a client which is implemented by me, WCF shows a better performance in terms of request per second. the client is implemented as follows:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int input = 10;
    int inst = 1000;
    Test(input, inst);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
async static void Test(int input, int inst)
{
    Task[] tasks = new Task[input];
    TimeSpan sp = new TimeSpan();
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < input; i++)
    {
        tasks[i] = myFunc(i, inst);
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("elappsed time: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    Console.WriteLine("successfull requests: " + ((input * inst) - errorcounter));
    Console.WriteLine("unsuccessfull requests: " + (errorcounter));
    Console.WriteLine("average request per second are sent:" + (input * inst) * 1000 / sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

}
static string baseAddress = "address to the service";
static int errorcounter = 0;
static object mylock = new object();
static Task myFunc(int i, int count)
{
    return Task.Run(async() =>
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
        {
            try
            {
                WebClient wc = new WebClient();
                await wc.UploadStringTaskAsync(baseAddress, "");
            }
            catch
            {
                lock (mylock)
                {
                    errorcounter++;
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Using this code as a client WCF can handle more than 160 requests per second in my system, but ASP.Net core Web API handle 80 requests per second. It means that WCF is 2X faster?!?! But as indicated in [test on round 13](https://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/#section=data-r13&hw=ph&test=json) it should be handle more requests I think. [Stephen Cleary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary) mentioned in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41189289/the-best-option-for-building-a-high-traffic-system-using-c-sharp#comment-69597467) this site.
Is there a specific configuration that can speed up ASP.Net core Web API?!
Does anyone know that using `kestrel` as a web server is better or `weblistener`?!

I have to mention that I have compared these 2 codes using IIS, IIS Express (in visual studio), using a better hardware (with more cpus, cores and ram) and the same result was obtained.

---

**Update:**

I have to mention that I use [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api) to implement asp.net core web api.

---

**Update2:**

The test is done using another machine and because of our business type we have to implement a high performance server no matter how the clients use this service (sync connection or async/await in webclient).

---

**Update3:**

I have updated the client code and make it asynchronous to optimize the performance and the results.

Comment: Your test is completely useless. It doesn't use async, it doesn't cache the WebClient, it doesn't use pipelining, Use a proper tool like `wrk` for http request benchmarking. See http://github.com/aspnet/benchmarks  for the official asp.net core benchmark repository for some sample commands and results

Comment: @Tseng you are right, but note that the test in not for usability, I think it is a fair test to compare these 2(If i do not miss something like a special config)! If I want to use async/await or cache webclient etc... it is clear that both the systems show improvements!

Comment: Yea, but your test has no point. You are creating the WebClient within a loop, so you're not just measuring the creation of the client. Also your ASP.NET Core application is not using async, which effectively will suffer thread starvation, especially when your client also blocks threads as it doesn't run async. So assuming an 4 core CPU with HT that's 4 threads blocked on the client and 4 threads blocked on the server, which can run at the same time. Just use a proper tool for testing it and run server and test client on different machines

Comment: BTW, your interpretation of round 13 data is completely wrong. ASP.NET Core is fast in static page serving and so on, but is not that fast in other categories. Besides, using Application Insights can slow down your web apps in certain degree. People choose ASP.NET Core for many reasons and performance is not the only one.

Comment: As Lex already pointed out, this is not even an apples-to-apples comparison since (presumably) the WCF example is not using Application Insights telemetry. IMO, a better way to approach this is to pick a framework you are comfortable with and write your application in a way that is horizontally scalable. If you need more performance, add more machines in a cluster.

Comment: Thank you all. @Tseng, @lex-li, @nate-barbettini...
First of all, my client is on another machine. Secondly, on round 13 there is a test to serve `Jason` which is not known as static resouce. I believe that using a suitable config and dlls we can have a better performance...

Comment: @Tseng would you please tell me how can I use pipelining or cache webclient?!

Comment: Look at the first comment I posted, there is a link. It has command line instructions for wkt and how to set it up